# For a large mapreduce job, with a few lingering reducers, can this job be safely downsized?

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

Chris Smith answered this question and said I could post it.

If you have a 200-node mapreduce job, with just 3 running reduce jobs
left lingering, is it safe to switch off all nodes except the master
and the 3 with the running jobs?
Plus maybe a handful more in case of a bad node needing replacement?

If the answer to this question is "yes" it's strange that emr doesn't
automatically turn off most of the nodes nodes when they're not in
use.

Lately there's been several jobs that mostly finished, but with a few
reduces lingering. I think this is costing us since the not-in-use
nodes stay up.

There are these issues I can think of:

-- when does data get copied to S3? If a node is not in use in terms
of running reduce, could it still be needed for copying to S3? In that
case, answer to my question is you're basicaly never safe to switch
off nodes
-- what happens if one of 3 jobs fails? Master/job coordinator should
reassign it to another node. I guess you're safe as long as it can
keep track of what boxes are up, and not wrongly assign to a box that
has been shut off.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have a 200-node mapreduce job, with just 3 running reduce jobs
>   left lingering, is it safe to switch off all nodes except the master
>   and the 3 with the running jobs?
>   Plus maybe a handful more in case of a bad node needing replacement?
>
> If the answer to this question is "yes" it's strange that emr doesn't
>   automatically turn off most of the nodes nodes when they're not in
>   use.

Keep in mind, EMR is a very thin layer over Hadoop. If you were doing distributed computation on Amazon's fabric, you could be a TON more efficient with something customized for its specific needs which would not really resemble Hadoop or Map/Reduce at all. If you're doing a lot of heavy work with Hadoop, you are often better off with your own cluster or at least with a dedicated cluster in the cloud (that way data is already sliced up on local disk and output need only be persisted to local disk). EMR's main virtue is that it is quick and dirty and hooks in nicely to other parts of AWS (like S3).

> Lately there's been several jobs that mostly finished, but with a few
>   reduces lingering. I think this is costing us since the not-in-use
>   nodes stay up.

It most definitely is costing you, particularly in terms of runtime. I'd start by being concerned about why the completion times are so non-uniform.

> There are these issues I can think of:
>
> -- when does data get copied to S3? If a node is not in use in terms
>   of running reduce, could it still be needed for copying to S3? In that
>   case, answer to my question is you're basicaly never safe to switch
>   off nodes

If you are referring to the output of a job, if you have S3 as your output path for your job configuration, then data from a given task will be written out to S3 before the task exits.

> -- what happens if one of 3 jobs fails? Master/job coordinator should
>   reassign it to another node. I guess you're safe as long as it can
>   keep track of what boxes are up, and not wrongly assign to a box that
>   has been shut off.

Well... it's a bit more complicated than that... When the new node is assigned the job, it has to pull the data from somewhere. That somewhere it typically from the mappers who generated the data in the first place. If they aren't there anymore, the map tasks may need to be rerun (or more likely: the job will fail). Normally the replication factor on map output is 1, so this is an entirely plausible scenario. This is one of a few reasons why Hadoop jobs can have their "% complete" go backwards... mappers can even go back from 100% to <100%.

Related to this: it's conceivable, depending on the stage those reducer jobs are in, that they have yet to receive all of the map output that feeds in to them. Obviously in THAT case killing the wrong mapper is deadly.

I think it is important to highlight the difference between taking offline TaskTracker only nodes, vs. nodes running TaskTracker + DataNode service. If you take off more than a couple of the latter, you're going to lose blocks in HDFS, which is usually not a great thing for your job (unless you really don't use HDFS for anything other than distributing your job). You can take off a couple of nodes at a time, and then run a rebalancer to "encourage" HDFS to get the replication factor of all blocks back up to 3. Of course, this triggers network traffic and disk I/O, which might slow down your remaining tasks.

tl;dr: there can be problems killing nodes. While you can be confident that a completed task, which writes its output to S3, has completely written out all of its output by the time the JobTracker is notified the task has completed, the same can't be said for map tasks, which write out to their local directory and transfer data to reducers asynchronously. Even if all the map output has been transferred to their target reducers, if your reducers fail (or if speculative execution triggers the spinning up of a task on another node), you mail *really* need those other nodes, as Hadoop will likely turn to them for input data for a reassigned reducer.

--
Chris

P.S. This can actually be a big pain point for non-EMR Hadoop setups as well (instead of paying for nodes longer than you need them, it presents as having nodes sitting idle when you have work they could be doing, along with massive compute time loss due to node failures). As a general rule, the tricks to avoid the problem are: keep your tasks sizes pretty consistent and in the 1-5 minute range, enable speculative execution (really crucial in the EMR world where node performance is anything but consistent), keep replication factors up well above your expected node losses for a given job (depending on your node reliability, once you cross >400 nodes with day long job runs, you start thinking about a replication factor of 4), and use a job scheduler that allows new jobs to kick off while old jobs are still finishing up (these days this is usually the default, but it was a totally new thing introduced ~Hadoop 0.20 IIRC). I've even heard of crazy things like using SSD's for mapout dirs (while they can wear out fast from all the writes, their failure scenarios tend to be less catastrophic for a Hadoop job).